# How is the decay of a signal exemplified in a Fourier Transform?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, phase, ifft, amplitude

Is there any way to tell if a signal is decaying from its fourier transform?

Comment: Is it possible to post a plot with a view of your signal?

Comment: I don't have a specific signal.  I'm interested in any insight into what phenomena decay (monotonous) introduces into the fourier transform

Comment: Be more specific give a mathematical formula for your problem then we can help you otherwise I have to flag it as unclear of what you are asking.

Comment: I edited to be more specific

Comment: _All_ signals that have finite energy and thus have Fourier transforms in the classical sense (no impulses a.k.a. Dirac deltas anywhere) _must_ decay away to $0$ as $t \to \infty$ or $\to -\infty$. So a dead giveaway is "no impulses in Fourier transform? signal decays"

Comment: @DilipSarwate that's been my understanding and part of the reason I asked this question.  I don't feel like I get why that's so beyond intuition from looking at different signals. Do you think you could write an answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is there any way to tell if a signal is decaying from its fourier transform?

From a single Fourier transform, no there is not, if we assume 'decay' to mean a decrease in amplitude or power over time. Amplitude and time are the variables which define a time domain signal, magnitude and phase are the variables which define a frequency domain signal (that of the Fourier transform).

If you have *multiple* Fourier transforms of a signal, each one from a different time period of the signal (for example with [Short time fourier transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform)) then you can determine the decay in the signal amplitude, by frequency, over time. Implicitly you could also derive the total loss of power in the signal and so its net 'decay'. It should however be noted that this is an inefficient method of determining the decay in signal power/amplitude compared to using the time domain representation.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. See my comment on the OP's question.

Comment: Your understanding of the question is obviously different from mine, you should post your answer to expand your explanation rather than downvoting mine. I do not personally understand what "no impulses in Fourier transform" is supposed to mean.